# cordova with phaser3 not working ios music, sound is muted

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Music works in android, but in ios music dont play. In emulator, iphone 11 work but in iphone 8 and below dont work.

```
this.load.audio("musicSound", bgSound);
this.load.audio("paperSound", paperSound);
this.load.audio("gameOverSound", gameOverSound);
this.load.audio("akuAkuMusicSound", akuAkuMusicSound);
this.load.audio("warScreamSound", warScreamSound);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put this in config.xml:

```
<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true" />
```